# i want to convert this function in to the Php function

Tags: java, php, function

```
private void CharsAvailable()
        {
            int num = 0;
            int num2 = 0;
            string text = this.txtMessage.Text;
            if (this.chkSignature.Checked)
            {
                text = text + Environment.NewLine + this.txtSignature.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                text = this.txtMessage.Text;
            }
            int num3 = 0;
            while (num != 1 && num3 < this.txtMessage.TextLength)
            {
                if (text[num3] < '0' || text[num3] > '9')
                {
                    if (text[num3] < 'A' || text[num3] > 'Z')
                    {
                    }  
                 ..............................
                   SOME CODE 
                 ............................

                if (num == 1)
                {
                    int num4 = text.Length;
                    if (num4 <= 70)
                    {
                        num4 = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        num4 += 62;
                        num4 -= num4 % 63;
                        num4 /= 63;
                    }
                    frmCompose.isUnicodeFound = true;
                    this.lblChar.Text = string.Concat(new object[]
                    {
                        text.Length,
                        " characters, ",
                        num4,
                        " SMS message(s)"
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    int num4 = text.Length + num2;
                    if (num4 <= 160)
                    {
                        num4 = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        num4 += 152;
                        num4 -= num4 % 153;
                        num4 /= 153;
                    }
                    frmCompose.isUnicodeFound = false;
                    this.lblChar.Text = string.Concat(new object[]
                    {
                        text.Length + num2,
                        " characters, ",
                        num4,
                        " SMS message(s)"
                    });
                }
            }

            //validation

                        if (this.txtMessage.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Blank messages cannot send. Please type the message.", "Blank Message");
                        }
                        else if (frmCompose.isUnicodeFound && this.cmbLanguage.SelectedIndex == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please choose 'Unicode' in Language dropdown to send message(s) in non English.”", "Unicode Message");
                        }enter code here
```

I want some help to convert this function in to the php function  . what is the similar syntex or similar function in  the relevant function in the php code . anybody can help with this . if i get some of the changes list need to make then it would be great .Thanks in advance .

Comment: The mother of all if statements :D

Comment: What the hell ?! why 1000 time se same condition ? text[num3] != '?' and why not only increment and check the other cases?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any nesting beyond 7 should be refactored.

Comment: i know its the complex code and often uses of the 'if' statement  but this is the code which i have i need some help if possible  .

Comment: @Abhicenation, first post a question on how to simplify deeply nested if-statements.

Comment: It's not complex, it's awfull. There are better ways to check if a character is valid. Look into regex or something.

Comment: Do you know what a regular expression is?

Comment: i dont want to change the code just need the help with the relevant  php code

Comment: i have remove the some of the repeat code .

Comment: **First correct your java code!!!** - make use of array, loop (use switch:case  and regex)...Then anyone could help you converting it to PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i highly recommend to refactor your code before converting this to PHP. This is simply done by having two array and loop over them both whilest checking the characters. This will replace most of the statements.

A example ( in php ):

```
 $characters = array("{", "}", "\\", "[", "]", "~", "|", "€");
    $text = array();
    $num = 0;
    $num2 = 0;
    $num3 = 0;

    foreach($characters as $char)
    {
        if($text[$num3] == $char  ) 
        {
            $num2++;
        }else
        {
            $num = 1;
        }
    }
```

I've tried to keep the logic of the current code intact. Only implemented less obsolete/redundant.

Now this leaves us with the first 3 if statements. This is a perfect canidate for regex. Using preg_match in PHP you can easily replace those 3 if statements.

A PHP example:

```
    $text = "abcABC123";
    $regex = "/[a-zA-Z0-9]/";

    if(preg_match($regex, $text))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
```

For the rest of the code is fairly straight forward and is mostly logic. One thing is for sure, please look into how to implements certain things more effeciently. It helps you and people who will work with the code in the future :)